# Can android phones use other os

Tags: stock-android

As we have virtual machines to computers,is there any for android where users can use other operating systems on their mobile device?

Comment: Virtual machines and running an OS are two different things though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Android is a special Linux underneath it all and can run other Linux instances. Check [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zpwebsites.linuxonandroid&hl=en) out. Im not sure about other OS because it depends on driver support and platform type (for ex. I dont know can normal Windows run on ARM processors, maybe Windows RT can).

And besides, you have the whole Ubuntu phone project.